# How to soley wrap the <input>-field in a custom <div>-wrapper in Webform 4.x?

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I've a fairly simple question. Due to a given CSS I need to wrap the `<input>`-field (as well as `<select>` or `<textarea>`) of webform-component with a custom `<div>`-wrapper.

Change the follwoing ->

```
<div class="webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--title">
    <label for="edit-submitted-title">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-title" name="submitted[title]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
</div>
```

to ->

```
<div class="webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--title">
    <label for="edit-submitted-title">Name</label>
    <div class="my-custom-class">
         <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-title" name="submitted[title]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/95142/webform-how-to-wrap-each-form-field-with-a-div) snippet (changing #prefix and #suffix with [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)), but it wraps the whole webform-componoent in a custom div.

Result is like this:

```
<div class="my-custom-class">
    <div class="webform-component webform-component-textfield webform-component--title">
        <label for="edit-submitted-title">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="edit-submitted-title" name="submitted[title]" value="" size="60" maxlength="128" class="form-text required">
    </div>
</div>
```

I also tried to modify #field_prefix and #field_suffix with, but it doesn't result in any output at all. It seems, that these doesn't allow to have any custom html in it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use hook_form_alter and add "'#title_display'    => 'none'," and use label in prefix. e.g.

```
if($form_id == "content_type_node_form"){
   $form['field_name']['#prefix'] = '<label for="edit-submitted-title">name</label><div class="newclass">';
   $form['field_name']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
}
```

I have not tested it but this can work.

Answer (score 0):

It is not supported currently - not in any easy way - and you should not need it. Creating `div` for only one element provides no benefit over adding a class to that element, you should be able to style it however you feel like if you will use `hook_form_alter` with something like:

```
$field['#attributes']['class'][] = 'my-custom-class';
```

And then just attach whatever styles you want directly to input - it should be possible to achieve whatever look you need that way.

Comment: As I said I need to wrap the input field due to given CSS. The page has a custom design, but uses some parts of twitter bootstrap element styling, in this case forms. As you can see in the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal) it's a common approach to style forms like this. Since I don't want to completely rewrite the CSS, for me the most straight foward way is to change the output of webform. I thought, using `hook_form_alter()` is the easiest way. Maybe there is another way like building a custom *.tpl.php. I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you exactly mention your field name as in content type that will add the div in that field

add this in form alter for that particular form.

```
if($form_id == "content_type_node_form"){
    $form['field_name']['#prefix'] = '<div class="newclass">';
    $form['field_name']['#suffix'] = '</div>';
}
```

this is how i used to add and wrap div
hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize all input template](https://www.drupal.org/node/1089656) files ( and maybe that need some work), another simpler solution is using jquery

use [jquery wrap function](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)  and try something like

```
$("input.edit-submitted-title").wrap("<div class='my-custom-class'></div>");
```